# Android Studio configuration problems

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm new in the android development world.
After Android Studio download I've tried to run my first HelloWorld.
But Android Studio give me any problem that I'm not understand how to solve.

In the first basic code in the class `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.elavora.helloworldandroid;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
   }
```

To the override it tells me

> "method does not override any method from its superclass".
>    Is it a serious problem?

And when I try to run project , the console tells me

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugUnitTestApkCopy'.
>   Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>        Required by:
>            HelloWorldAndroid2:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Received fatal alert: access_denied

Can anyone help me?
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your `app/build.gradle` file in the `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {
    //... other dependencies
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
}
```

You also need to specify where to get this dependency from. In the project's `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: it tells me :(

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:(9, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'HelloWorldAndroid2'.
> Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [junit:junit:4.12] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: You normally do, I put that in there just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, it appears to be simple proxy configuration in android studio, so in case you'r working under some organization proxy it might solve your problem.
go to File->settings->HTTP Proxy and setup your proxy properly.